# Truffle - Migrations cannot be found

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I have recently done a fresh install of truffle v2.1.1 as I want to compare this version to the recently updated version.

```
truffle init
```

Works as expected.  However, when doing;

```
truffle migrate --reset
```

This error is returned;

```
Could not find expected contract or library in 'ConvertLib.sol': contract or library 'ConvertLib' not found.
```

Before, I had deleted ConvertLib and MetaCoin to try this with a newly created contract.  However, the error still remains for the Migrations contract and the newly created contract.

I have also tried to modify the deploy_contracts.js to include;

```
deployer.deploy('.....directory...ConvertLib')
```

And also modified the initial_migrations.js file;

```
deployer.deploy('.....directory...Migrations')
```

Would anybody be able to help as I have created multiple fresh truffle folders to try this on but nothing seems to be helping.  Thanks!

Comment: If ConvertLib.sol has been deleted at ConvertLib library is nowhere to be found, then the migration shouldn't be trying to deploy it. In 2_deploy_constracts.js, only deployer.deploy() contracts with source files it can find. Hope it helps. Keep MIgrations.sol. It's important.

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, when the file is not deleted, the same error occurs.  It is as if it isn't finding the contracts folder.  When i deleted the MetaCoin and the ConvertLib as they are both testing contracts and aren't crucial to truffles operations.  The same error occurs but for Migrations now.  Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js is trying to deploy the contracts that have been deleted.